# Terminate EC2 instance and not root EBS (Attached root EBS to new instance)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have created an instance running ubuntu os. Now I need to change the OS from ubuntu to cent OS. For that I need set the "**deleteOn Termination**" flag as false to attach it to the new instance.

I used the following command but it tells -> "**Only one instance ID may be specified. (-h for usage)**"

ec2-modify-instance-attribute --region  device=vol-id:false

I am struck with this few hours. Can any one answer for this; How to resolve this issue?

Thanks for the reply in advance

Comment: Is there any reason you can't do this in the web interface?

Comment: The ec2-modify-instance-attribute command must have an instance ID specified.  I don't see that in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can do this, but I can help you with the problem.

For this, first take the snapshot of the volume you want, and then simply create a new Volume out of it, and then attach it to the new instance.

Should work for your scenario.

Comment: Would you care to accept the answer please so that other people can also be helped with this.

Comment: What I have done is stopped the instance and detached the EBS root volume and then created new instance and attached the volume. Finally I have terminated old instance.